# PDF not validating value of zero

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a form with a check box that validates that all of the text fields have values. If there is no value, then it displays a JavaScript warning window that says: Error! You must fill in the following fields. The required fields with no data are then listed.

Problem is that if the value is zero it gives the warning. Zero is an acceptable value and I don’t want it to give the warning in this case.

```
var emptyFields = [];
for (var i=0; i<this.numFields; i++) {
     var f= this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));
     if (f.type!="button" && f.required ) {
          if ((f.type=="text" && f.value=="") || (f.type=="checkbox" && f.value=="Off")) emptyFields.push(f.name);
     }
}
if (emptyFields.length>0) {
     app.alert("Error! You must fill in the following fields:\n" + emptyFields.join("\n"));
}
```

Comment: Type these in any JavaScript console to see the difference: `0 == ""`, `0 === ""`.

Comment: Álvaro, afraid I have no clue what the above is in reference to in relation to my question.

Comment: You say you're displaying the warning for `0` values, and that's the reason. Is this code yours, or it's inherited from some predecessor?

Comment: It is inherited

Comment: I've never ever written JavaScript code in PDF files, but the language itself is loosely typed so you have two comparison operators: `==` discards types and make implicit conversions, `===` considers types and make strict comparisons. This is the part that makes warnings to be added: `(f.type=="text" && f.value=="") || (f.type=="checkbox" && f.value=="Off")`